# Mongoose schema validation error while updating document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update an existing a document in one of the collection in MongoDB.Mongoose is throwing a validation error Message":

```
 "local_transport_details validation failed: contact.residingcountry: Path `contact.residingcountry` is required., 
contact.postalCode: Path `contact.postalCode` is required., 
contact.city: Path `contact.city` is required., 
contact.addressLine1: Path `contact.addressLine1` is required., 
name: Path `name` is required., 
providerID: Path `providerID` is required."
```

Script works perfectly fine if transportSchema.save function is called.

Is it mandatory to save document after every edit?If yes can you please help me to get rid of this validation error?

Model-

```
var localTransportSchema = new Schema({

    providerID: { type: Number, required: true, trim: true, unique: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    contact: {
        addressLine1: { type: String, required: true },
        addressLine2: { type: String, required: false },
        city: { type: String, required: true },
        postalCode: { type: Number, required: true },        
        primaryContactNumber: {type: Number,required: true},           
        secondaryContactNumber: {type: Number,required: false},
        serviceActiveFlag: { type: String, required: false, enum: ['Y', 'N'] },
    }, 
    vehicle: [{
        vehicleType:{ type: String, required: false, enum: ['sedan', 'hatchback', 'suv', 'mpv', 'luxury'] },        
        activeFlag: { type: String, required: false, enum: ['Y', 'N'] },
    }]
});
```

Controller code

```
      module.exports.updateLocalTransportVendorDtls = function (req, res) {

     var transportSchema = new transportModel();
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        checkForNewVehicleType(req, function (doc) {
            resolve(doc)
        })
    })
    .then(function (doc) {
        var updateJustServiceDtls = doc.split(/\|/)[2];        
        if (updateJustServiceDtls == 'true') { /* To update service details for the same vendor */
            return updateJustServiceDetailsOnly(req, res)           
        } 
    }).then(function () {
        transportSchema.save(function (error) {
            if (error) {
                logger.error("Error while updating record in transport details collection: - " + error.message)
                return res.status(500).json({ "Message": error.message.trim() });
            }            
        })

    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.json({ "Message": err.message });
    });
}
```

Function -

```
var updateJustServiceDetailsOnly = function (req, res) {

    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        transportModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": req.body['providerName'], "contact.postalCode": parseInt(req.body['postalCode']) },
            {
                "contact.addressLine1": req.body['addressLine1'],
                "contact.addressLine2": req.body['addressLine2'],
                "contact.city": req.body['city'],
                "contact.postalCode": parseInt(req.body['postalCode']),                
                "contact.primaryContactNumber": parseInt(req.body['primaryContactNumber']),                
                "contact.serviceActiveFlag": req.body['serviceActiveFlag'],
            }, { returnOriginal: false, upsert: true }, function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {                    
                    return reject(res.status(409).json({
                        "Message": "Error while updating transport details for provider " + req.body['providerName'] + " in transport details table"
                    }));
                } 
                resolve();
            });
    })
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: you do not want to run validation on update ?

Comment: yes.I want to run validation only for the fields i update.In my case i am not updating providerID & name.Because those are not going to change and i want mongoose to ignore validation for those two fields.

Comment: It works fine if i remove transportSchema.save function from promise chain in controller code.Fields are getting updated as expected.Is this approach correct?