# How to skip mongoose schema validation during update API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

One of the field in my model is defined as

providerID: { type: Number, required: true,unique: true }.

providerId is a unique number inserted when the provider details are inserted for the first time.There are instances where i need to update provider details like,name address etc.During update api call,mongoose throws validation error for the field 'providerID' through i don't alter it at all.

Is there any way to skip/ignore the validation of 'providerID' during api calls?
Ideally i am expecting mongoose to throw validation error during insert api call and skip the validation during update api call.

Comment: Hm... are you sure you are not altering the `providerID` upon updating? If you update an existing document keeping some of the required or unique fields intact, there shouldn't be any problems. Post your schema and code for how you insert and update.

Comment: You may find the model and controller code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355932/mongoose-schema-validation-error-while-updating-document?noredirect=1#comment79676078_46355932

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess from looking at your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355932/mongoose-schema-validation-error-while-updating-document).

```
 transportModel.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, { returnOriginal: false, upsert: true }, callback);
```

Your `findOneAndUpdate()` is using the `upsert: true` option i.e. *creates the object if it doesn't exist*. Is it possible the object does not exist? If so, it would try and create a new object with the data you provided without a `providerID`, which would then trigger the error.

Run a quick test using `findOne()` with the same conditions.

```
 transportModel.findOne(conditions, function (err, model) {
     if (!model)
         console.log('something is wrong with your data or conditions');
 });
```

Comment: I removed upsert: true findOneAndUpdate query,but no luck